# VIM copy doesn't work in Gnome Terminal (to system clipboard)

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, gnome, clipboard

I prefer using VIM in a gnome terminal (On Fedora 19) instead of using GVIM.

But I can't seem to copy to the system clipboard.

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out because other threads showing hacky xclip stuff never worked for me.

My VIMRC: [.vimrc on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/RuLDfHfc)

Which contains

```
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
```

also

```
vmap <C-c> "+yi
vmap <C-x> "+c
vmap <C-v> c<ESC>"+p
imap <C-v> <ESC>"+pa
imap <C-v> <Esc><C-v>a
```

My GNOME terminal has the following keyboard shortcut setting:

Copy = Ctrl+C
Paste = Ctrl+V

(also tried with ctrl-shift-c and it didnt make a different)

Is there some Fedora/Gnome thing I need to add? GNOME Shell version is 3.8.4.

My vim version data is here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JTxYNbUF

Comment: To start with, don't use `+=` to add "unnamedplus" to 'clipboard'. Use `^=` instead. With `+=`, "unnamedplus" will be put after the "exclude:" portion of 'clipboard' and won't be seen as the "unnamedplus" option.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work either. when I highlight text in VIM using the mouse in gnome terminal, the copy command is greyed out too. So I'm not even sure if this is a VIMRC thing or a gnome terminal issue

Comment: Could you add the full output of `$ vim --version` to your question?

Comment: If you are using the terminal vim that came with Fedora 19, it probably wasn't built with support for X11 or the clipboard. Execute `:version` and look for `X11` and `xterm_clipboard`. They should both have `+` in front of them. If they have `-` in front instead, you'll need to use a different build of vim. The easiest way to do that is to put `alias vim=gvim -v` in your ~/.bashrc. The `-v` option will run gvim in terminal mode, and gvim is always built with support for X11 and the clipboard.

Comment: Have you tried highlighting the desired text and then clicking the mouse wheel to paste?  I know this won't fix the grayed out copy option but it should allow you to copy and paste.  If your mouse has no wheel, then you can click both the left and right buttons together to create the middle-click.

Comment: Here is the output of my $vim --version http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JTxYNbUF

Comment: using gvim -v seems to work when I yank things, thanks garyjohn I guess I'll use that as an alias

Comment: Your Vim doesn't have clipboard support. You can probably use your package manager to install a better version.

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to copy-and-paste with `y` or with your gnome-terminal snhortcuts? The latter should be working normally even without `clipboard`.

Answer (score 5):

Since you shared your version data, I can see that it says `-clipboard`. This means that vim wasn't compiled with the `+clipboard` feature, thus it can't access the system clipboard. You can probably remedy this by installing a `vim-gtk` package or equivalent. If you compiled it yourself, just add the appropriate flag.